# Modelbase (inheritance) with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

i would use a ModelBase with an ID and a Timestamp for every class/entity. But when i user the `Long` type for the Primary Key in the `JPARepository<>` interface i get the message

```
Not an entity: class java.lang.Long
```

**Code:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ModelBase implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "datetime")
    private Date lastModified;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getLastModified() {
        return lastModified;
    }

    public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
        this.lastModified = lastModified;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    public void updateLastModified() {
        lastModified = new Date();
    }

}
```

**Modelclass inheritanced from Modelbase**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Name")
public class Name extends ModelBase implements Serializable {}
```

**Repo**

```
public interface NameRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, Name>{}
```

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's backwards:

```
JpaRepository<Name, Long>
```

First the entity, then the ID. Check JPARepository javadoc.